# Problem with Visual Studio and .NET framework

Tags: visual-studio

From a few days ago I'm facing annoying problems with Visual Studio and .net framework. 
First I couldn't use breakpoints, but after a few changes I'm able to.

Yesterday, I've changed my Model of Entity Framework and renamed a few columns. Now the web server assumes that no change have been made.

I've made a simple test: removed a condition that I had in my masterpage where I checked a session and created a breakpoint there, when I run it VS goes to the breakpoint, the condition isn't there but he keeps working like it was.

I've tried to use the fusion log to check assembly errors on run time but none give me errors.

I can only assume that I'm not running the "newest" version of the project but I don't know why.

Comment: +1 for `I've madded an simple test` - you rock!

Comment: What's the point? I'm Portuguese, i don't speak or write native English..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your dlls are out of date. Try using the option "Clean Solution" and then re-build the solution.